# Is the condition in the for loop evaluated in every loop?

Tags: javascript, optimization

I have a situation like:

```
for(var i = 0; i < a + b; ++i)
  // code that doesn't affect a and b
```

Should I worry about the addition been performed in every iteration? Or JavaScript (its parser?) is smart enough to understand that `a + b` is constant?

In other words, should I do that like this:

```
var end = a + b;
for(var i = 0; i < end; ++i)
  // code
```

or will this waste a line of code?

---

Well, actually what I worry about is not that one line of code, BUT the fact that I am thinking about it every time I face a situation like this in JavaScript! Also, ***today it's an addition, tomorrow it may be something else, like the square root of it, so I think it's important!***

Comment: i pretty sure that this evaluate on every iteration

Comment: Even if `a + b` is called every time, it won't have an important impact because the addition is fast. If there will be `sqrt(a+b)` then it will be a good idea to extract it into a variable because this is an expensive operation. Of course, it also depends on the estimated value for that upper bound.

Comment: I would imagine it's evaluated on every line, but it would be down to the optimiser in whatever javascript implementation is running the code.  If it's smart enough, it may optimise it out.  Once you've profiled the code (_properly_) and you've found that performing that check yourself is slowing things down, that's the time to worry about optimising it manually.

Comment: That's what I am afraid of @Grundy.

Comment: I would add the line for readability, regardless of the gain in performance, which, btw, would be minor for most current engines.

Comment: @helpYou, big truth! James, thus you suggest I should cache the summation, thanks!

Comment: @illiptic: I would avoid the extra line for the same reason (unless there's a much more descriptive name than `end` for the variable) :-) Agree that the performance is negligible.

Comment: "*I worry about the fact that I am thinking about it every time I face a situation like this*": [**Stop worrying!**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimisation)

Comment: @Bergi that's why I got the downvote? I agree..

Comment: Interpreter might optimize the `a+b` part or it may not. Like Bergi said.

Comment: @gsamaras: You didn't got a downvote (from me), and there are none at your question currently.

Comment: @Bergi I didn't say you downvote me, but when I asked you, I had two. Thanks for the link! Salman, thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's better to define the constant like this :

```
for(var i = 0, end = a + b; i < end; ++i)
```

---

**Optimization way**

You can write your loop like this :

```
for(var i = a + b; i--;)
```

This is for me the more optimized but `i` is descending and not ascending

---

**More example**

A simple example to understand. If you create your loop like this :

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) { 
   array.push('value'); // infinite loop
}
```

`array.length` is evaluated on every iteration and you can create an infinite loop with `array.push()`.

Comment: Nice way of writing it.

Comment: I'm unsure how your 2nd example lends weight to your argument - you could equally put `end++` within the loop and have the same problem.  If you're going to write bad code, you'll get bad results...

Comment: @JamesThorpe True, I changed the example

Comment: Yes, that's a more understandable issue now - would be a more subtle bug, but essentially still bad code :)

Comment: This might be a good suggestion but has nothing to do with the question. I can't really understand why it has been chosen as the accepted answer.

Comment: @gsamaras I add another way to write your loop, it's for me the more optimized

Comment: Because it removed my argument for wasting an extra line of code. Howeevr, R3tep, I removed the part of your answer that was the same with Andrea's, who made a really good answer (and got my upvote), so that content is not repeated. Thanks all! @AndreaCasaccia I upvoted an answer of yours that I liked as a sorry for un-accepting your answer (and mostly because of Knuth's perfect comment).

Answer (score 8):

The condition is going to be evaluated each time.

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

```
for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
   statement
```

> **condition**: An expression to be evaluated *before each loop iteration*. If
>   this expression evaluates to true, statement is executed. This
>   conditional test is optional. If omitted, the condition always
>   evaluates to true. If the expression evaluates to false, execution
>   skips to the first expression following the for construct.

(Italic is mine)

There *could* or *could not* be an optimization on a sub-expression of the condition, depending on the engine: when you have a similar doubt the fastest thing you can do is to setup a test and measure performances.

According to [this test](http://jsperf.com/so32824175/2) for example the two versions take the same time on the latest Chrome and Firefox.

However, the rule of the thumb about this kind of optimizations is: **do not prematurely optimize**. From [Program optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize) on Wikipedia:

> "*We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time:
>   premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass
>   up our opportunities in that critical 3%*"
>
> Knuth, Donald (December 1974). "Structured Programming with go to
>   Statements". ACM Journal Computing Surveys 6 (4): 268. CiteSeerX:
>   10.1.1.103.6084.

Write functionally correct code, without worrying about such small or doubt performance issues. When executing, if you find you have a performances problem, dig in and optimize.

**TL; DR**

You shouldn't be worried about this, the performance impact is likely to be minimal, and modern javascript engines seem to optimize this anyway.

But if you are still worried, writing a line of code doesn't seem to me a big waste. So why don't just you do that, and stop thinking about it?

Comment: Note that that means the _whole condition_ is evaluated each loop iteration.  If the optimiser is smart, it might cache sub-sections of it still (ie the `a+b` the OP is asking about)

Comment: I know, this is why I say *There could be an optimization or not depending on the engine* in the next paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

It will be evaluated for each loop but a simple addition operation such as the a + b that you used in the example is generally such an easy operation that you won't see a noticeable difference one way or the other. That being said, it is a better idea to just add a and b together before the loop as in your second example.